# toggleSwitch Selenium Button for searchtempest.com

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

On search tempest I am trying to find the location of the toggle switch button under sources, but I cannot seem to find any location where I can toggle the toggle switch with python selenium.  The website follows:

https://www.searchtempest.com/search?search_string=desk&category=8&subcat=sss&hasPic=&maxAsk=&maxYear=&minAsk=&minYear=&srchType=&cityselect=zip&location=90210&maxDist=500&region_us=1&region_can=1&region_mex=1&Region=combined&addCities=&subCities=&q=desk++%22for+sale%22

I click on the sources button under the searchfilters which prompts a submenu to appear on the screen, and I would like to deselect everything but eBay results.

I have tried to use find by xPath, css_selector, by class, and nothing has worked.  I can't find the location and am unable to untoggle the desired sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code, which will untoggle all the options except eBay results.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe");
driver.get("https://www.searchtempest.com/search?search_string=desk&category=8&subcat=sss&hasPic=&maxAsk=&maxYear=&minAsk=&minYear=&srchType=&cityselect=zip&location=90210&maxDist=500&region_us=1&region_can=1&region_mex=1&Region=combined&addCities=&subCities=&q=desk++%22for+sale%22");

element = driver.find_element_by_id('hybridSearchPreferencesToggle')
element.click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='showcl_hybrid']/parent::div")
sleep(3)
element.click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='showat_hybrid']/parent::div")
element.click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='showaz_hybrid']/parent::div")
element.click()

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='showzr_hybrid']/parent::div")
element.click()

print("Done...")
```

I have used sleep() method for giving 3 seconds delay before doing the un-toggling, you can replace this with WebDriverWait if you want to.

```
clicked=False
count=30
while not clicked or count > 0:
    try:
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='PUsnl' and text()='Done']/parent::button")
        element.click()
        print("Clicked...")
        break
    except:
        print("Not Clicked...")
    sleep(1)
    count-=1
```

Use the above code for clicking on the 'Done' button. As some pop up is coming on the right side 'Welcome to tutorial mode', the above code will wait until that pop up gets disappeared then will click on the 'Done' button

You can try to close that pop up instead of waiting for that pop up to gets disappeared or you can use WebDriverWait for 'Done' locator until it becomes clickable. I hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been stuck on this for days.  Would you mind taking me through what you did and also how to press the "Done" button once done toggling?

Comment: Welcome... This is all about just getting the XPath, as toggle buttons are identified using the div tag, we need to take reference from input tag which identify the toggle button.